# Created Tables and Streams not showing as Topics

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-platform, ksqldb

I can successfully create and see tables and streams in KSQL, but they are not showing as topics so I can consume them on a Java Kafka Consumer.

Brief of what's happening:

```
ksql> CREATE TABLE RTSHTABLE (primaryKey BIGINT, secondaryKey BIGINT) WITH (KAFKA_TOPIC = 'rtsh', VALUE_FORMAT='JSON', KEY='primaryKey');

 Message
---------------
 Table created
---------------


ksql> SHOW TABLES;

 Table Name | Kafka Topic | Format | Windowed
----------------------------------------------
 RTSHTABLE  | rtsh        | JSON   | false
----------------------------------------------

ksql> SHOW STREAMS;

 Stream Name         | Kafka Topic                 | Format
------------------------------------------------------------
 RTSHSTREAM          | rtsh                        | JSON
 KSQL_PROCESSING_LOG | default_ksql_processing_log | JSON
------------------------------------------------------------

ksql> SELECT * FROM RTSHTABLE LIMIT 5;
1555406522968 | m�l | 1830743660 | 1968383301
1555406522969 | 0��N | 819984462 | 1390795850
1555406522969 | m�� | 1830743753 | 1968383301
1555406522969 | m� | 1830743691 | 1968383301
1555406523501 | o)� | 1865005575 | 797470537
Limit Reached
Query terminated

ksql> SHOW TOPICS;

 Kafka Topic                 | Registered | Partitions | Partition Replicas | Consumers | ConsumerGroups
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 default_ksql_processing_log | true       | 1          | 1                  | 0         | 0
 rtsh                        | true       | 1          | 1                  | 0         | 0
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Well, I need to consume data from RTSHTABLE from a Java Kafka Consumer, but it's not working since the consumer can't connect to a topic named RTSHTABLE.

I've read in the documentation that a KTable is considered as a topic and can be consumed normally like any other topic. So, What am I missing here?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The topic for `RTSHTABLE` is `rtsh`. That's exactly what `SHOW TABLES` is telling you:

```
ksql> SHOW TABLES;

 Table Name | Kafka Topic | Format | Windowed
----------------------------------------------
 RTSHTABLE  | rtsh        | JSON   | false
----------------------------------------------
```

Tables and Streams are just semantic models on top of topics. In your SQL code quoted about you are just 'registering' the table on an existing topic.

If you `CREATE STREAM foo AS SELECT …` or `CREATE TABLE foo AS SELECT …` then it will create an underpinning topic too.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I'm still trying to get the full image here. So I have to create a table that gets data from a topic using `WITH` statement, then create another table that gets data from the previous table but using `AS SELECT`? That's what I have now and it's working, but I wonder if there is a direct way to create a table from a topic and is still accessible as a topic. The reason I want this table is to have the latest values only.

Comment: If you want to consume a topic as if it is a table (access latest values only) from Java then use Kafka Streams library. This has the same concepts of tables (KTables), and you can materialise the state as you require there.